# ASP.NET ADO.NET contact form

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

Let me start of by saying that I am new to ASP and have done my best to learn the script the past couple weeks. I am having trouble setting up a aspx.cs page to get the information to post on the server. Any help would be much appreciated.

The web form is one page that needs to collect text fields, RadioButton, dropdownlist, and checkboxlist. for the checkboxlist it would be nice to just collect a 1 if it is selected and a 0 if not selected.

It needs to be able to work with asp.net 2.0, IIS 6, C#, SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        //sets the connection string from your web config file "ConnString" is the name of your Connection String
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConString"].ConnectionString;
    }

private void ExecuteInsert(string 1, string 2, string 3, string 4, string 5, string 6, string 7, string 8, string 9, string 10, string 11, string 12, string 13, string 14, string 15, string 16, string 17, string 18, string 19, string 20, string 21, string 22, string 23, string 24, string 25, string 26, string 27, string 28, string 29, string 30, string 31, string 32, string 33, string 34, string 35, string 36, string 37, string 38, string 39, string 40, string 41, string 42, string 43, string 44, string 45, string 46, string 47, string 48, string 49, string 50, string 51, string 52, string 53, string 54, string 55, string 56, string 57, string 58, string 59, string 60, string 61, string 62, string 63, string 64, string 65, string 66)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    string sql = "INSERT INTO webContactForm (1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66) VALUES (@1,  @2,  @3,  @4,  @5,  @6,  @7,  @8,  @9,  @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16, @17, @18, @19, @20, @21, @22, @23, @24, @25, @26, @27, @28, @29, @30, @31, @32, @33, @34, @35, @36, @37, @38, @39, @40, @41, @42, @43, @44, @45, @46, @47, @48, @49, @50, @51, @52, @53, @54, @55, @56, @57, @58, @59, @60, @61, @62, @63, @64, @65, @66)";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[66];
        //param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Contact_id", SqlDbType.Int, 20);
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[3] = new SqlParameter("@4", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[4] = new SqlParameter("@5", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[5] = new SqlParameter("@6", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[6] = new SqlParameter("@7", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[7] = new SqlParameter("@8", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[8] = new SqlParameter("@9", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[9] = new SqlParameter("@10", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[10] = new SqlParameter("@11", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[11] = new SqlParameter("@12", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[12] = new SqlParameter("@13", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[13] = new SqlParameter("@14", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[14] = new SqlParameter("@15", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[15] = new SqlParameter("@16", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[16] = new SqlParameter("@17", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[17] = new SqlParameter("@18", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[18] = new SqlParameter("@19", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[19] = new SqlParameter("@20", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[20] = new SqlParameter("@21", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[21] = new SqlParameter("@22", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[22] = new SqlParameter("@23", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[23] = new SqlParameter("@24", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[24] = new SqlParameter("@25", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[25] = new SqlParameter("@26", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[26] = new SqlParameter("@27", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[27] = new SqlParameter("@28", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[28] = new SqlParameter("@29", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[29] = new SqlParameter("@30", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[30] = new SqlParameter("@31", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[31] = new SqlParameter("@32", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[32] = new SqlParameter("@33", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[33] = new SqlParameter("@34", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[34] = new SqlParameter("@35", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[35] = new SqlParameter("@36", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[36] = new SqlParameter("@37", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[37] = new SqlParameter("@38", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[38] = new SqlParameter("@39", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[39] = new SqlParameter("@40", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[40] = new SqlParameter("@41", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[41] = new SqlParameter("@42", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[42] = new SqlParameter("@43", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[43] = new SqlParameter("@44", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[44] = new SqlParameter("@45", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[45] = new SqlParameter("@46", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[46] = new SqlParameter("@47", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[47] = new SqlParameter("@48", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[48] = new SqlParameter("@49", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[49] = new SqlParameter("@50", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[50] = new SqlParameter("@51", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[51] = new SqlParameter("@52", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[52] = new SqlParameter("@53", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[53] = new SqlParameter("@54", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[54] = new SqlParameter("@55", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[55] = new SqlParameter("@56", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[56] = new SqlParameter("@57", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[57] = new SqlParameter("@58", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[58] = new SqlParameter("@59", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[59] = new SqlParameter("@60", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[60] = new SqlParameter("@61", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[61] = new SqlParameter("@62", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[62] = new SqlParameter("@63", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[63] = new SqlParameter("@64", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[64] = new SqlParameter("@65", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[65] = new SqlParameter("@66", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
    param[66] = new SqlParameter("@67", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);

        param[0].Value = 1;
        param[1].Value = 2;
        param[2].Value = 3;
        param[3].Value = 4;
        param[4].Value = 5;
        param[5].Value = 6;
        param[6].Value = 7;
        param[7].Value = 8;
        param[8].Value = 9;
        param[9].Value = 10;
        param[10].Value = 11;
        param[11].Value = 12;
        param[12].Value = 13;
        param[13].Value = 14;
        param[14].Value = 15;
        param[15].Value = 16;
        param[16].Value = 17;
        param[17].Value = 18;
        param[18].Value = 19;
        param[19].Value = 20;
        param[20].Value = 21;
        param[21].Value = 22;
        param[22].Value = 23;
        param[23].Value = 24;
        param[24].Value = 25;
        param[25].Value = 26;
        param[26].Value = 27;
        param[27].Value = 28;
        param[28].Value = 29;
        param[29].Value = 30;
        param[30].Value = 31;
        param[31].Value = 32;
        param[32].Value = 33;
        param[33].Value = 34;
        param[34].Value = 35;
        param[35].Value = 36;
        param[36].Value = 37;
        param[37].Value = 38;
        param[38].Value = 39;
        param[39].Value = 40;
        param[40].Value = 41;
        param[41].Value = 42;
        param[42].Value = 43;
        param[43].Value = 44;
        param[44].Value = 45;
        param[45].Value = 46;
        param[46].Value = 47;
        param[47].Value = 48;
        param[48].Value = 49;
        param[49].Value = 50;
        param[50].Value = 51;
        param[51].Value = 52;
        param[52].Value = 53;
        param[53].Value = 54;
        param[54].Value = 55;
        param[55].Value = 56;
        param[56].Value = 57;
        param[57].Value = 58;
        param[58].Value = 59;
        param[59].Value = 60;
        param[60].Value = 61;
        param[61].Value = 62;
        param[62].Value = 63;
        param[63].Value = 64;
        param[64].Value = 65;
        param[65].Value = 66;
        param[66].Value = 67;

        //create loop to insert
        for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
        }

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Error occured while inserting:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    }
    private object GetConnectionString(string p)
    {
throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        //call the method to execute insert to the database
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MyParamter", "my value"));

        ClearControls(Page);
}
}
```

## WEB FORM CODE:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"" Inherits="Default2" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Contact Us</title>

  </head>
   <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
      <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 1:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 2:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="LName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">3 TextBox column 3,4,5:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="3" runat="server" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>-
                <asp:TextBox ID="4" runat="server" Width="59px"></asp:TextBox>-
                <asp:TextBox ID="5" runat="server" Width="62px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 6:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">ListItem column 7:</td>
            <td class="style2">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="7" runat="server"
                              AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>D</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>E</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>F</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>G</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">RadioButton column 8</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="Yes" runat="server" Checked="True" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="No" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 9:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="9" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 10:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="ClientLName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">RadioButton Column 11:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="Female" runat="server" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="Male" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">3 TextBox column 12,13,14:</td>
            <td class="">
                <asp:TextBox ID="12" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>(mm)/<asp:TextBox ID="13" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>(dd)/<asp:TextBox ID="14" runat="server" Width="85px"></asp:TextBox>(yyyy)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 15:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="15" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 16:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="16" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 17:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="17" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">Dropdownlist column 18:</td>
            <td class="style2">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="18" runat="server"
                              AppendDataBoundItems="true">
         <asp:ListItem value="-1">Select State</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="AL">Alabama</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="AR">Arkansas</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="AZ">Arizona</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="CA">California</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="CO">Colorado</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="CT">Connecticut</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="DC">District of Columbia</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="DE">Delaware</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="FL">Florida</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="GA">Georgia</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="IA">Iowa</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="ID">Idaho</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="IL">Illinois</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="IN">Indiana</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="KS">Kansas</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="KY">Kentucky</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="LA">Louisiana</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MA">Massachusetts</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MD">Maryland</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="ME">Maine</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MI">Michigan</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MN">Minnesota</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MO">Missouri</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MS">Mississippi</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MT">Montana</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NC">North Carolina</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="ND">North Dakota</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NE">Nebraska</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NH">New Hampshire</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NJ">New Jersey</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NM">New Mexico</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NV">Nevada</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NY">New York</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="OH">Ohio</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="OK">Oklahoma</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="OR">Oregon</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="PA">Pennsylvania</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="RI">Rhode Island</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="SC">South Carolina</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="SD">South Dakota</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="TN">Tennessee</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="TX">Texas</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="UT">Utah</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="VA">Virginia</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="VT">Vermont</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="WA">Washington</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="WI">Wisconsin</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="WV">West Virginia</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="WY">Wyoming</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 19:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="19" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <h1>
        Providing:
       </h1>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="20">Want 1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="21">Want 2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="22">Want 3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="23">Want 4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="24">Want 5</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="25">Want 6</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="26">Want 7</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="27">Want 8</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="28">Want 9</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="29">Want 10</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="30">Want 11</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="31">Want 12</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="32">Want 13</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="33">Want 14</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="34">Want 15</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="35">Want 16</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="36">Want 17</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="37">Want 18</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="38">Want 19</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="39">Want 20</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="40">Want 21</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </td>
        <td>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="41">Want 22</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="42">Want 23</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="43">Want 24</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="44">Want 25</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="45">Want 26</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="46">Want 27</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="47">Want 28</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="48">Want 29</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="49">Want 30</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="50">Want 31</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="51">Want 32</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="52">Want 33</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="53">Want 34</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="54">Want 35</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="55">Want 36</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="56">Want 37</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="57">Want 38</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="58">Want 39</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="59">Want 40</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="60">Want 41</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="61">Want 42</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">Comment TextBox column 62:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="62" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>
              <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList3" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="63">Have 1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="64">Have 2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="65">Have 3</asp:ListItem>
              </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </td>
            <td>
              <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList4" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="66">Have 4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="67">Have 5</asp:ListItem>
              </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                         onclick="Button1_Click" />
</form>
```

Comment: post some code of what you have been trying so far..

Comment: Need some see your "Try at Least" code to see if its a logic pattern or a class usage problem.

Comment: Sorry about that I added what I have so far for the aspx.cs page

Comment: What are you having trouble with exactly?

Comment: I have added the web form code as well. @jrummell - I am not sure that I am coding the back end properly so that it will upload to the server.

Comment: @Clay, good job on using parameterized queries for your insert.  You would be surprised how many .NET newbies don't know to do this.

Comment: Also - Are you getting a specific error?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @AbeMiessler - Thank you, and like I said I did attempt to learn a lot before I started asking questions :) , and the error that I am getting is "Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected. Line 214:            Response.Write("We will contact you shortly!");
Line 215:            ClearControls(Page);
Line 216:}"

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to use `Response.Write()` as it can break your web form if used improperly. Try using a `Label` or `Literal` control instead.

Comment: @jrummell if it is a problem I really don't even need to worry about that at this point and time I deleted it and added a } to close the _default class that Abe Miessler mentions below.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** after seeing your error message it sounds like you are missing a trailing `}`.  From your code it looks like you could add one at the very end to get around this error message.  Basically you don't have a closing `}` for your `_Default` class declaration right now.

---

I don't see anything in your code that jumps out as a problem.  I would recommend placing a break point on the first line of your onclick event handler and then step through your code line by line to confirm everything is working as expected. Make sure to make use of "step into" (f11) since you have a lot of internal functions.  That said I think you could make your code a lot easier to read (and debug) if you declared/added parameters in the following way:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MyParamter", "my value"));
```

This could eliminate over 60 lines of code and make this a much easier problem to tackle.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are saying here. Can you elaborate a little bit? Thank you for the advice.

Comment: In the code behind sample you posted you should add a `}` character after the very last character in the sample.  All classes in .NET need to have an opening `{` and a closing `}`.  Currently your `_Default` class (which holds all of your code) has an opening `{` but no closing `}`.  This could just be a copy/paste issue, but if it really exists in your code it would explain your issue.

Comment: Yes I added that at the end and understood what you were saying in reguards to closing the _Default class. I was talking about the cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MyParamter", "my value"));

Comment: I have edited my code to reflect my interpretation of your recommendation. I am also getting an error in Visual web developer: "The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"